# Website Visible only to Registered users

Tags: login, user-access

How can I disable access non registered users? If the user is not logged in I would like to redirect them to a custom registration/login page. Is it possible this using below code as I dont want to use plugin.

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo 'Welcome, registered user!';
} else {
    echo 'Welcome, visitor!';
}
?>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Write this into a plugin:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'auth_redirect' );
```

As [plugin on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/3521964).

This will force all visitors login if they aren’t already.

In some cases, this is asking for a log-in *every time*. This might work better:

```
is_admin() || add_action( 'template_redirect', function() {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() )
        auth_redirect();
});
```

If you want to send a 404 status instead, you can replace the `auth_redirect()` with:

```
wp_die( 'Nope.', 'Not found', [ 'response' => 404 ] );
```

Comment: Hi, Is there any way to redirect it to a specific page?

Comment: By default the visitor will be redirected to the page she tried to see. You could write a wrapper very similar to `auth_redirect()` and set `$login_url` to a specific page.

Comment: I think it can be even simpler removing `is_user_logged_in()` and leaving only `auth_redirect()` because `auth_redirect()` works as follow: if the user is logged in it does nothing. If the user is not logged in it redirects him/her to login page.

Comment: @cybnet Without that extra check, [it fails sometimes](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/100573/73).

Answer (score 3):

If you don't feel like changing your code, you could use this plugin instead: [Restricted Site Access](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/restricted-site-access/). It's highly rated and in my personal experience, it works really well.

> Limit access your site to visitors who are logged in or accessing the site from a set of specified IP addresses. Send restricted visitors to the log in page, redirect them, or display a message or page. A great solution for Extranets, publicly hosted Intranets, or parallel development / staging sites.

Answer (score 0):

You probably just have to put the following in your `functions.php`:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo 'Welcome, registered user!';
} else {
    wp_redirect(site_url('/wp-login.php?action=register'));
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the Answer its easy by css..

1. main div(.lor1) means comman div start after header and finesh before footer
2. Add new class (.lor1.kun) in main div when user loging this main class display: block;
3. make new html Ex. display mess loging frist one (.lor1.user_not_login)

**ADD this code in header.php**

```
 <?php     
if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
?> 
<style>
.lor1{ display:none;}
.lor1.kun{ display: block;}
.lor1.user_not_login{ display: block;}
</style>
<?php }  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, your code is actually functional. You just have to call the right modules in the right places.

```
if( !is_user_logged_in() ){
    // show_registration_panel() 
} else {
   // He is a registered user. Proceed as usual
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add This Function to your functions.php file.

when user not login access on 
home page(page id ==2) to redirect on login page.

```
<?php
add_action('template_redirect','wpse64899_check_if_logged_in');
function wpse64899_check_if_logged_in()
{
    $pageid = 2; // or whatever you want it to be
    if(!is_user_logged_in() && is_page($pageid))
    {
        $url = add_query_arg(
            'redirect_to',
            get_permalink($pageid),
            site_url('wp-login.php')
        );
        wp_redirect($url);
        exit;
    }
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your Child's themes of Parent themes function.php file

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_to_specific_page' );

function redirect_to_specific_page() {

if ( is_page('home') && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {

wp_redirect( 'https://example.com/login', 301 ); 
  exit;
    }
}
```

Please replace "home" with the page slug name, i.e this is the page you don't want your users to access without logging in and replace this url "https://example.com/login" with the destination url where you want to redirect your users if they are not logged in, i.e this url should direct to your login or registration page.