# How to lock content?

Tags: posts

What is the easiest method to make all my articles accessible only to registered users?

My homepage contains titles and excerpts but I want to allow access to the full content only to registered users.

I remember there was an admin setting for that but I cannot find it.

Maybe Im wrong. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could hook into `template_redirect`, check if it is a singular page (post, page, custom post type) and force a log in:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'login_to_see_content' );

function login_to_see_content()
{
    if ( is_singular() && ! is_user_logged_in() )
        auth_redirect(); // does nothing for logged in users
}
```

As suggested by @s_ha_dum in the comments, an additional `! is_user_logged_in()` might be necessary. In theory, it shouldn’t (and it isn’t in my setup).

Comment: Thanks. Where do I add this? functions.php ?

Comment: @p.a. Make a [little plugin](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/72160/where-do-i-put-the-code-snippets-i-found-here-or-somewhere-else-on-the-web), so you can turn it off easily.

Comment: Thanks, my needs are minimal so I ll just drop this into functions.php. I just check for a "public" category and redirect for all other categories to the login box.

Comment: No it does not work; it always redirects me to login. Even if I am connected as admin!

In addition, when redirected, login does not work! I supply valid credentials and return to login screen.

Comment: @p.a. I tested my solution: It works. Do you have by any chance another plugin enabled that breaks this functionality?

Comment: What plugin might be illegal?

Comment: @p.a. Some user role managers have their own ideas how to handle logged in users. You should update your question with the changes you made to my code.

Comment: I use it with no changes: I put this in functions.php:

//block all contents for un-registered users
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'login_to_see_content' );

function login_to_see_content()
{
    if ( is_singular() )
        auth_redirect(); // does nothing for logged in users
}

Comment: Something else is broken then. I have used this code in many projects, it works everywhere.

Comment: Maybe in the login screen there is a requirement? Can you please send me your login screen code? Thanks.

Comment: It works without any other customization: standard WordPress installation plus the plugin above.

Comment: @toscho : I am also getting a login loop with your code-- WP 3.5.1, no active plugins, Twenty Twelve. I had to add a `!is_user_logged_in()` condition to make it behave. _I don't know why_. `auth_redirect`, by all appearances, should take care of that.

Comment: @s_ha_dum Hm, *maybe* there is a cookie validation bug when the post is password protected?

Comment: @toscho : it is not a password protected post. I don't know what is happening. I am puzzled. I tried deleting all of the domain cookies as well.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend a plugin like [User Access Manager](http://wordpress.org/plugins/user-access-manager/) for that purpose. It gives more function and control than using native function such as making posts Private.