# I lock the site's contents, click on a post, redirect to login, enter uname+password but fail to redirect to article

Tags: wp-login-form

As stated in the following:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/100573/16266

I lock the site's contents.

I then click on a post.

I am navigated to wp-login screen.

I enter the correct username + password of admin.

I am never returned back to the article but remain stuck in wp-login without any feedback.

Please help..

Comment: This seems like the same topic as in the thread you mention. Why did you start a new question?

Comment: See my update in my answer to your former question. Please do not ask the same question again, and do not accept my answer until it is solved. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to edit your redirect function to redirect back to the post where you were before redirection

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'login_to_see_content' );

function login_to_see_content()
{
  if ( is_singular() && ! is_user_logged_in() )
       auth_redirect(); // does nothing for logged in users
  }
```

to this

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'login_to_see_content' );
function login_to_see_content(){
   if(is_singular() && ! is_user_logged_in()){
      $url= site_url()."/wp-login.php";
      $url.='?redirect_to="'.urlencode ($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] );
      wp_redirect($url);
   exit;
 }}
```

Comment: Thanks this is almost what I needed.
Unfortunately, it blocks my home page. I cannot see my homepage without logging in.
Help please... Thanks!

Comment: Try Now . I have corrected this code.

Comment: It works! I am very grateful! This was really hard for me, I tried many alternatives. Thank you very much Vikas!