# What hook to add at start of WordPress load

Tags: hooks, actions

I want to add a hook that is the first thing that runs every and any time someone hits a page, post or other WP piece of content on my site, and before anything else in WordPress executes.

Can you help me with what that hook should look like?

Is it `init` ?

Does it look like this: `add_action('init', 'callMyFunction');`

Or this: `do_action('init', 'callMyFunction');`

Thank you.

Comment: In a plugin or theme? Try this https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

Comment: Yep, been there for quite some time before posting @BradDalton...it does not provide a direct or easily understandable answer to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The earliest hook accessible from external code is `muplugins_loaded`. In order to use it, create a directory `mu-plugins` in your `wp-content` directory and put a PHP file into that directory.

Sample code, will have side effects(!):

```
add_action( 'muplugins_loaded', function() {
    print current_filter();
});
```

This is, of course, not "before anything else in WordPress executes". WordPress has to run some code to *load* such a mu-plugin. You can find the hook it in `/wp-settings.php`. Right above that call, you can see what happens before.

The real question here is **why** you think you need to run code so early. This is almost never needed.

If you want to require a log-in for some sites, wait for `plugins_loaded` (`is_user_logged_in()` doesn't work earlier) and do something like this:

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', function() {

    if ( is_user_logged_in() )
        return;

    $protected_sites = [1, 4, 7];

    if ( in_array( get_current_blog_id(), $protected_sites ) )
        auth_redirect();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for helping and clarifying @toscho. I am trying to put my entire site behind a firewall. I want to force any and every visitor to the site to have to login into WP before being able to see ***any*** page, post, or other piece of content. [FYI Note: this site is not for wide public consumption. It is restricted to a handful of authorized users]

Comment: @tammy Like [this solution](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/100573/73)?

Comment: Also, thanks for suggesting making it an MU plugin. I can't go that route because I am running a Multisite network and I only want 1 of my sites to be behind this firewall, not every site in my network.

Comment: @tammy _mu_ means _must-use_ not _multisite_.

Comment: Yep, I know that @tosco. But MU/must-use means that each and every site in my Multisite network gets the plugin and uses the plugin. Thus I cannot make the plugin I am trying to develop a must-use plugin.

Comment: Then just install [this one](https://gist.github.com/toscho/3521964) for one site.

Comment: I looked at your plugin @toscho. I am not sure it will serve my needs. I have completely altered the WordPress user authentication process and installed my own method for all users in our MS Network to authenticate through a different means. So I already have the function I need to call that launches our customized auth process. I am just looking for the best place to put my hook into for this 1 particular site to intercept the general public and cause them to go through my auth process before gaining access to any piece of content behind the firewall.

Comment: You can use `get_current_site()` in a mu-plugin and adjust the code top run only when you are on the correct site.

Comment: Interesting...@mrhenko's comment on your github code post is piquing my interest. Days ago, I did a search for a plugin solution and my search arguments did not turn up either of the 2 plugins @mrhenko is referencing. I am going to look at those to see if I can save myself from writing my own plugin at this time.

Comment: *You can use get_current_site() in a mu-plugin and adjust the code top run only when you are on the correct site.* excellent tip @toscho ... thank you for sharing that. I like learning new things and getting new ideas. I'll definitely utilize that code option at some point in one of my many MU Plugins.

Comment: it does not look like either of the plugins mentioned above will do what I need, so I will forge ahead and write my own. Thanks @toscho for helping guide me to the best method to achieve the solution I need.

Comment: @tammy See my update. I have added an example that should solve your use case.

Comment: Thanks @toscho ... I'll try to work that out. Because I am getting Internal Server 500 errors on `if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) $abc=123;`

Comment: Thanks @toscho -- I got it to work. I preferred to use `if ( in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $GLOBALS['privateURLs']))` as my protected sites...but let me ask you, **if I use site ID will Wordpress catch all pages, posts and other content (such as the media library)?**

Comment: @tammy Everything that is routed through WP. Not single media files, they are accessed directly.